# I have to create a CI CD pipeline to integrate repos in azure to linux server

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

My azure repos contains all the folders , and changes will be made by the users in the azure repos.
I want to create CI CD pipeline in azure repos to integrate azure repos and the linux server. Whenever some changes done in the azure repos should reflect in the linux server.

I want to know, how to implement the above scenerio.

Comment: What does "integrate azure repos and the linux server" mean? Are you saying your Linux server has git installed and you want to push your repos into it? Why?

Comment: Yes, git installed in my linux server, and i want to create a ci cd pipeline to clone the azure repos with linux server ...... whenever the azure repos is updated with some changes, the changes has to be updated in the linux server too.... i need to create ci cd pipeline for the above scenerio.

Comment: Why do you want two copies of your source code in two different repos?

Comment: Code in the azure repos will be changes often by the user, so we need it as a back up in the linux server

Comment: That's the whole point of version control. You can go back to any commit you like. You are solving a problem that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can try to install a new [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) in your Linux server.

And then in your CI pipeline, you can use the git clone command to clone the repo in your Linux server.

You can also use the [copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) task to copy the folder of the repo the to the UNC path.